# Rails 3 Formtastic form not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

Here is my form view code:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= semantic_form_for @new_athlete_sport, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "new_sport", :"data-type" => 'json', :id => '' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Sport" %>
    <%= f.select :sport_id, Sport.all.collect { |sp| [sp.name, sp.id] }, {}, { class: "chosen", id: "" }  %>
    <br />
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

For some reason the `<form>` tag isn't showing up in the DOM, but every other fields show up..

Answer (score 0):

Seems the syntax in form_for has some problem.

Try remove "id" and move "data-type" from this

```
<%= semantic_form_for @new_athlete_sport, :remote => true,
:html => { :class => "new_sport", :"data-type" => 'json', :id => '' } do |f| %>
```

to this

```
<%= semantic_form_for @new_athlete_sport, :remote => true, :data=> {:type=> 'json'}, :html => { :class => "new_sport"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: That didn't work :( It doesn't make sense cause this syntax is what is being used through the site for other forms